# c++ - Preprocesador - Duda existencial

Tags: c++, c, git, preprocesador

realmente tengo una duda existencia, y a medida que avanzo me hace mas ruido y realmente no sé si estoy haciendo las cosas bien. Tengo un software propio, que he desarrollado hace unos meses atras...va bastante bien en su finalidad, pero resulta que me han pedido otro que tiene la funcionalidad del anterior pero que agrega funcionalidades adicionales...osea, el primero se basa en el segundo.
Lo que a mí se me ocurrió, es sobre el juego de fuentes, definir una constante a nivel del proyecto y agregar sentencias del preprocesador...en principio se me ocurrió que era lo mejor...de esa manera solo cambiaría en lugares claves solo cuando necesito clases nuevas de la nueva funcionalidad...PERO a medida que avanzo veo que se complica y el código se vuelve in-mantenible. Muestro partes para que vean que me esta sucediendo.

```
#include "enginegraph.h"
#include "trackfarmgraph.h"
#ifdef __CORTE_SECCION__
#include "multiworkerdpathgraph.h"
#else
#include "workedpathgraph.h"
#endif
#include "pointsfarmgraph.h"
```

.... en otras partes del proyecto ...

```
pointsGraph = NULL;
#ifndef __CORTE_SECCION__
    worker = NULL;
#else
    multiWorker = NULL; 
#endif
engine = NULL;
dlg = NULL;
```

.... en otras partes del proyecto ...

```
#ifndef __CORTE_SECCION__
if (worker)
{
    disconnect(worker);
    delete worker;
    worker = NULL;
}
#else
if (multiWorker)
{
    disconnect(multiWorker);
    delete multiWorker;
    multiWorker = NULL;
}
#endif

if (track)
{
    disconnect(track);
    delete track;
    track = NULL;
}
```

Con esto voy notando que el código se torna ilegible y con el tiempo lo será mas. 
La ventaja que encuentro es que si aparecen bugs en la parte comun, se corrigen y ambos software quedan OK...pero el costo de ilegibilidad y mantenimiento creo que crece exponencialmente.
De que otra forma se puede hacer esto?. GRACIAS

Comment: Personalmente creo que estás enfocado el problema desde una perspectiva equivocada. Los gestores de versiones tipo git, svn, mercurial... son las herramientas adecuadas para realizar esas tareas. Te harán la vida más fácil. Mantendrás distintas ramas de desarrollo del código, podrás fusionarlas, marcar releases y demás. Utilizar el preprocesador para mantener distintas versiones del software... bajo mi modesta opinión es una solución que no escala, te valdrá para un par de casos, en cuanto crezca el proyecto será un auténtico galimatías.

Comment: @Neoniet justamente eso es lo que estoy consultando. Como harias un merge entre 2 ramas pero solo de algunos files?...porque si tengo un bug en un file comun a las 2 soluciones, necesito aplicarlo a las 2 ramas...como seria?

Comment: a ver si te vale la respuesta @Emiliano Torres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a poner un ejemplo sencillo.

Iniciamos un repositorio

> git init

Añadimos los archivos iniciales del programa

> git add main.cpp Clase1.cpp Clase1.hpp
>
> git commit -m "Programa inicial"

Un cliente nos pide una cosa muy especial que probablemente no le valdrá al resto. El cliente tiquismiquis!!
Pues nos creamos una rama

> git checkout -b clientetiquismiquis

Añadimos los nuevos archivos y las modificaciones de los antiguos

> git add *
>
> git commit -m "Versión para cliente tiquismiquis lista"

Ahora saltamos a nuestra versión principal para seguir mejorando el programa

> git checkout master

Añadimos las mejoras a la rama principal

> git add *
>
> git commit -m "Mejoras añadidas"

Y ahora queremos mejorar la versión del cliente tiquismiquis, pues nos vamos a su rama:

> git checkout clientetiquismiquis

y fusionamos con master

> git merge master

```
Auto-merging main.cpp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in main.cpp
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Leches!!! resulta que no puede fusionarlas automáticamente, pues abrimos el archivo en conflicto, lo dejamos bien a mano y seguimos

> git add main.cpp
>
> git commit -m "Fusionadas mejoras de master en clientetiquismiquis"

Todo listo :-)

Answer (score 3):

El problema en este caso es que no estás aislando correctamente las diferentes funciones.

Las directivas del preprocesador pueden aportar mucha flexibilidad al código... peeero distan mucho de ser perfectas:

- Cuantos más símbolos defines más complicado es mantener el código
- El código que queda fuera de un `#ifdef` no se compila, lo que te obliga a realizar varias compilaciones para probar todas las combinaciones (mantenimiento demasiado caro)
- Los símbolos no tienen tipado, es facil confundirse y poner `_CORTE_SECCION__` en vez de `__CORTE_SECCION__`... y entonces gasta horas en identificar el problema.

Lo recomendable es aislar las diferentes funcionalidades en clases o funciones. Con los nuevos estándares usar plantillas es una opción bastante asequible.

Me explico. Partamos de este fragmento de código:

```
#ifndef __CORTE_SECCION__
    worker = NULL;
#else
    multiWorker = NULL; 
#endif

// ...

#ifndef __CORTE_SECCION__
if (worker)
{
    disconnect(worker);
    delete worker;
    worker = NULL;
}
#else
if (multiWorker)
{
    disconnect(multiWorker);
    delete multiWorker;
    multiWorker = NULL;
}
#endif
```

Mejorarlo y aislar el código aquí es relativamente sencillo.

Lo primero que haría sería definir una constante en base a `__CORTE_SECCION__`:

```
#ifdef __CORTE_SECCION__
  constexpr bool IsMultiWorker = false;
#else
  constexpr bool IsMultiWorker = true;
#endif
```

A continuación podemos crear una colección de plantillas para los diferentes casos de uso (dos en este caso). Nota que no has indicado el tipo de `worker` y `multiworker`. Asumiré que son `Worker` y `Multiworker`.

El caso, nos interesa crear una herramienta que nos permita crear un `Worker` o un `Multiworker` según las circunstancias:

```
template<bool>
struct MultiWorkerTraits;

template<>
struct MultiWorkerTraits<false>
{
  using type = Worker;
};

template<>
struct MultiWorkerTraits<true>
{
  using type = MultiWorker;
};
```

Y seguidamente, las funciones de desconexión. Como la lógica a ejecutar es la misma nos basta con una única plantilla:

```
template<class T>
void Disconnect(T & worker)
{
  if( worker )
  {
    disconnect(worker);
    delete worker;
    worker = nullptr;
  }
}
```

Ya tenemos todos los mimbres listos, ya solo falta acometer cambios en el fragmento original de código:

```
typename MultiWorkerTraits<IsMultiWorker>::type * worker = nullptr;

// ...

Disconnect(worker);
```